# Chaining angularjs rest endpoint access

Tags: javascript, angularjs

To attempt to run angularjs rest sequentially I delay initial function by 1 second and next function by 2 seconds :

```
  setTimeout(function () {
  $http.get("/rest1")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.val1 = response.data;
  });
}, 1000)

  setTimeout(function () {
  $http.get("/rest2")
  .then(function(response) {
      $scope.val2 = response.data;
  });
}, 2000)
```

This approach is problematic as it's not guaranteed the second `rest` function will run after the first (although it's highly likely).

Can these `rest` calls be chained so that it's guaranteed `rest1` will execute after `rest2` ?

Comment: Not clear what relationship is. They both overwrite same scope variable and second doesn't seem to be dependent on data from first

Comment: You could just add another `.then` and make the second call inside it.

Comment: @charlietfl question updated, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of my latest tutorials covers this chaining of http requests: https://tutorialedge.net/angularjs-promises-tutorial

Wrapping it in a timeout function is basically the wrong way to go about it. As you said it's only 'highly likely' these promises will run one after another. Have a look at the chaining promises section of that post and you'll see how to guarantee sequential execution!

Below is the code sample extract from that post!

```
// first chop our 
$http.get('api/chop/onions')
  .then(function success(response){
    // once that is done chop our carrots
    return $http.get('api/chop/carrots');
  })
  .then(function success(response){
    // once the carrots are done, add both to the stew
    return $http.get('api/add/onionsAndCarrots');
  })
  .then(function success(response){
    // serve our stew
  });
```

Comment: link only answers have very little value here. Links rot and answer is not easy to review in context of other answers. Provide relevant code and only use link as support for what is in the question

Answer (score 1):

Definitely don't use timers on something with unpredictable timing.

Use a promise chain, for example:

```
$http.get("/rest1")
  .then((rest1Data) => {
    $scope.val1 = rest1Data.data;
  })
  .then(() => {
    return $http.get('/rest2');
  }).
  .then((rest2Data) => {
    $scope.val2 = rest2Data.data;
  });
```

Comment: should be assigning data property of each response object

Comment: @charlietfl Quite right, fixed.